# If $1 is /*, how do I echo $1 without emitting files matching the glob?

Tags: bash, sed

I have 4 parameters adding to excetute file:

```
./project01.sh /*  */  /^  ^/
```

and i want to make each parameters as variable
but before that i want to modify it because it will be unconvenient for futher operation. So i would like to make it like "/*" so put it in "" and before each character give \ because some of then are special characters.
I tried use like that:

```
beg1=echo $1 | sed(some change with $1)
```

but it change immediately $1 which is /* to direction /bin /boot itd. what can i do in that case?

Answer (score 1):

First, when calling your script, there's nothing you can do to avoid quoting. You **must** call it as:

```
./project01.sh '/*' '*/' '/^' '^/'
```

...if you want to prevent any potential for shell manipulation. (`^` is safe with some shells but not all).

This is because in the case of `./project01.sh /*` (without quotes), expansion happens **before the script is even started**, so once your script is running, it's too late to make changes.

---

Second, use more quotes within your script:

```
echo "$1" | sed ...
```

...or, better (to fix cases where `$1` contains `-E`, `-n`, or a similar value):

```
printf '%s\n' "$1" | sed ...
```

...or, better yet, if your shell is bash rather than `/bin/sh`...

```
sed ... <<<"$1"
```

**However, if your goal in using `sed` is to add syntax quoting to your arguments, this will never work: The arguments are already expanded before the script is even run, so `$1` is *already* `/bin`.**